# Syntax error when using simple query to database table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a very simple setup in Laravel while I'm learning it and I can't figure why I'm getting an error. It's probably something simple I am overlooking.

I can get this:

```
Route::get('users', function() {
    $users = User::all();
    return View::make('users')->with('users', $users);
});
```

example on Laravel to work perfectly, displaying this information in a users.blade.php view.

In my database I also have a 'lists' table but when I copy the structure of the code above to try and display my lists I receive the following error.

```
syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting '('
```

on line

```
 $lists = list::all();
```

---

My code is as follows
**routes.php**

```
Route::get('lists', function() {
    $lists = list::all();
    return View::make('lists')->with('lists', $lists);
});
```

**list.php** */models*

```
<?php
class List extends Eloquent {}
```

**lists.blade.php** */views*

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
@foreach($lists as $list)
    <p>{{ $list->name }}</p>
@endforeach
@stop
```

---

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: First glance, it looks like List _must_ be capitalized, since that's the name of your object. That is, try `$lists = List::all();`

Comment: @ChrisForrence Capitalising List::all(); still produces the error. Thanks however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List is a [reserved keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) in PHP, so you may not use it as a class name. From the documentation:

> These words have special meaning in PHP. Some of them represent things which look like functions, some look like constants, and so on - but they're not, really: they are language constructs. You cannot use any of the following words as constants, class names, function or method names.

Unfortunately, you're going to need to have a different class name, then set your object's table name to 'lists' like such:

```
class AppList extends Eloquent { protected $table = 'lists'; }
```

Comment: A decent editor usually shows this issue, based on syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisForrence - I'd never have guessed this!